# jQuery and img does function not

Tags: html, jquery, image

Happy new year!
I want the user to click on the image then load a video. I moved the id in the img to its div parent put nothing happened. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
<div class="card-body"> 
    <div class="embed-responsive">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="../images/Lesson 0 - Guitar Gears To Buy - 12-02-20.jpg" alt="Guitar Gears To Buy" id="Less0">
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Less0").click(function() {
    $(this).html('<iframe src="../videos/Lesson 0 - Guitar Gears To Buy - 12-02-20.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>').css('background', 'none');
        });
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't use `html()` on an image element. Try `$(this).parent().html(...` or `$(this).replaceWith(...`

Comment: I did not have this code in my header either
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#Less0").click(function() {
          $(this).replaceWith("<video src='../videos/Lesson 0 - Guitar Gears To Buy - 12-02-20.mp4' controls width='100%'></video>");

Comment: So what happens instead? Perhaps you are repeating the same ID in page?

Comment: I got it, thank u charlietfl !!!
      <div class="embed-responsive" id="Less0">